# Embedding python in C - Distribution

Tags: python, c, embed, importerror

I've embedded python into a C application on Windows. To distribute, I place the entire python folder next to my exe:

```
\Installation Dir
      app.exe
      script.py
      \python
```

As a test I made my C app very simple. It sets up the interpreter and attempts to run `script.py`.

Here are the entire contents of the C source:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    Py_OptimizeFlag=1;
    Py_SetPythonHome("python");
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();

    PySys_SetPath("python/Lib;python/DLLs;python/Lib/site-packages;");

    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
    PyObject* PyFileObject = PyFile_FromString("script.py", "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFileEx(PyFile_AsFile(PyFileObject), "script.py", 1);

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

This seems to work well...sometimes. 
On some machines I am getting `ImportError: DLL load failed` errors, usually referring to `_socket`.

I have explicitly set the path to point to the `Lib` and `DLLs` folder, so I do not understand why I get this error?

It must be some kind of conflict with an existing version of Python, but I have successfully installed on run this on other PC's with multiple versions of python already installed?

Are there some other variables or registry settings I need to set to ensure the embedded python can find what it needs?

Ideally, I would avoid setting registry values as I want this installation to be 'self-contained' and not potentially muck up any other version of python a user may install.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this on a PC that doesn't have python installed? I would expect `Py_SetPythonHome("python")` to be something along the lines of `Py_SetPythonHome("C:\Path\To\My\AppFolder")` rather than something relative...

Comment: unfortunately, i dont have a pc available without python installed! Im in the process of setting up a VM... Absolute paths are tricky because the user could install the program anywhere (potentially). But I suppose I could use `getcwd` in some way to construct the path

Comment: Yes, there are various ways of getting the current executable's path. Just do that and set that path + "/python" as pythonhome and I think you'll be in business...

Comment: @BrianSidebotham Set it up to use absolute paths, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I think this must somehow be related to the registry...not sure

Answer (score 0):

By searching for keyword: "_socket" in my python folder, I found something interesting. There is "_socket.lib" in "python/libs" folder, and "_socket.pyd" in "python/DLLs" folder. I don't know any details about this particular library, but I guess you can solve your problem simply by ***adding "python/libs" to the string you setup PySys_SetPath***. Or you can try to include more folders by referencing sys.path in your own all-OK environment.

The reason behind this guess is that I've heard that .pyd files basically plays the same role as .dll files when you do C/C++ programming. When you compile a dynamic-link library you generate .h, .dll and .lib files at the same time. The .dll contains the main code, and the .lib contains what is exported by the dll.